# Optimization Mysql Query Left Join

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join, query-optimization, explain

We want to map the entries of the calibration_data to the calibration data by following query. But the duration of this query is quite too long in my opinion (>24h).

Is there any optimization possible?
We added for testing more Indexes as needed right now but it didn't had any impact on the duration.

[Edit]

The hardware shouldn't be the biggest bottleneck

- 128 GB RAM
- 1TB SSD RAID 5
- 32 cores

EXPLAIN result

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                                          |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cal   | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    2009 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort                |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | NULL       | ALL  | visit         | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 3082466 |   100.00 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1) |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Query which takes too long:

```
Insert into knn_data (SELECT cal.X           AS X, 
        cal.Y           AS Y, 
        cal.BeginTime   AS BeginTime, 
        cal.EndTime     AS EndTime, 
        avg(m.dbm_ant)  AS avg_dbm_ant, 
        m.ant_id        AS ant_id, 
        avg(m.location) avg_location, 
        count(*)        AS count, 
        m.visit 
 FROM   calibration cal 
        LEFT join calibration_data m
          ON m.visit BETWEEN cal.BeginTime AND cal.EndTime 
 GROUP  BY cal.X, 
           cal.Y, 
           cal.BeginTime, 
           cal. BeaconId, 
           m.ant_id,
           m.macHash,
           m.visit;
```

Table knn_data:

```
    CREATE TABLE `knn_data` (
  `X` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Y` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `BeginTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `EndTIme` datetime NOT NULL,
  `avg_dbm_ant` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `avg_location` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visit` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ant_id`,`visit`,`X`,`Y`,`BeginTime`,`EndTIme`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table calibration

```
BeaconId, X, Y, BeginTime, EndTime
41791, 1698, 3944, 2016-11-12 22:44:00, 2016-11-12 22:49:00


CREATE TABLE `calibration` (
  `BeaconId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `X` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Y` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BeginTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `EndTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `x,y` (`X`,`Y`),
  KEY `x` (`X`),
  KEY `y` (`Y`),
  KEY `BID` (`BeaconId`),
  KEY `beginTime` (`BeginTime`),
  KEY `x,y,beg,bid` (`X`,`Y`,`BeginTime`,`BeaconId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table calibration_data

```
macHash, visit, dbm_ant, ant_id, mac, isRand, posX, posY, sources, ip, dayOfMonth, location, am, ar
'f5:dc:7d:73:2d:e9', '2016-11-12 22:44:00', '-87', '381', 'f5:dc:7d:73:2d:e9', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '12', '18.077636300207715', 'inradius_41791', NULL


CREATE TABLE `calibration_data` (
  `macHash` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `visit` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `dbm_ant` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `ant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mac` char(17) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `isRand` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `posX` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `posY` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `sources` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `dayOfMonth` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `am` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `ar` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `visit` (`visit`),
  KEY `macHash` (`macHash`),
  KEY `ant, time` (`dbm_ant`,`visit`),
  KEY `beacon` (`am`),
  KEY `ant_id` (`ant_id`),
  KEY `ant,mH,visit` (`ant_id`,`macHash`,`visit`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Comment: @Felix is there any overlap between your calibration times or are the intervals disjunct? So does every row in `calibration_data` belong to at most one calibration? You can probably reduce the runtime then by a lot (to like 30min with your amount of ram). Does the time values change for existing rows or do you just insert new rows? You can then probably go down to 1 min. And another question: is `BeaconId` a primary key for your `calibration` table or can it really be a) `null` and b) several entries with the same beaconId?

Comment: @Solarflare this is exactly the main problem. Every row at the calibration_data can belong to no or many calibration points. The tables are both historic data so there are no upcoming changes. The BeaconId can't be a primary key because the they are not unique. But the hint of Thomas reduced the calculation time to around 3h which is better than epic long requests.  But big thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's a nasty and classical one on "range" queries: the optimiser doesnt use your indexes and end up in a full table scan. In your explain plan ou can see this on column `type=ALL`.

Ideally you should have `type=range` and something in the key column

Some ideas:

---

I doubt that changing you jointure from

```
ON m.visit BETWEEN cal.BeginTime AND cal.EndTime
```

to

```
ON m.visit >= cal.BeginTime AND m.visit <= cal.EndTime
```

will work, but still give it a try.

---

Do trigger an `ANALYSE TABLE` on both tables. This is will update the stats on your tables and might help the optimiser to take the right decision (ie using the indexes)

---

Change the query to this might also help to force the optimiser use indexes :

```
Insert into knn_data (SELECT cal.X           AS X, 
        cal.Y           AS Y, 
        cal.BeginTime   AS BeginTime, 
        cal.EndTime     AS EndTime, 
        avg(m.dbm_ant)  AS avg_dbm_ant, 
        m.ant_id        AS ant_id, 
        avg(m.location) avg_location, 
        count(*)        AS count, 
        m.visit 
 FROM   calibration cal 
        LEFT join calibration_data m
          ON m.visit >= cal.BeginTime 
 WHERE m.visit <= cal.EndTime 
 GROUP  BY cal.X, 
           cal.Y, 
           cal.BeginTime, 
           cal. BeaconId, 
           m.ant_id,
           m.macHash,
           m.visit;
```

---

That's all I am thinking off...

Comment: Thanks!! Trying your solution with the on and where condition! The explain shows a filtered of 11.11 so it's worth testing

Comment: No `BETWEEN` is identical to the `>=`, etc.  Note a potential bug:  Both formulations are _inclusive_, so items at the boundaries may be included in two different buckets !

Comment: No to the `ON`.  Since it is less restrictive, it will scan extra rows.

Comment: @RickJames the aim is tro make it use the indexes not to scan less rows... Thank you for the downvote

Comment: Since this answer was accepted, did it really help? A lot? My main gripe with this construction is that all the records in `calibration` that have no corresponding record(s) in `calibration_data` will now be *excluded* from the resultset instead of showing up with a `NULL` value for the relevant `m.` fields. Essentially, you've converted the LEFT OUTER JOIN into an INNER JOIN. So yes, it might be faster, but no it's not the same thing. PS: I'm also a bit confused by having `m.macHash` in the GROUP BY while `cal.EndTime` isn't. As someone who usually works with MSSQL this feels so wrong to me..

Answer (score 1):

Onetime task?  Then it does not matter?  After getting this data loaded, will you *incrementally* update the "summary table" each day?

Shrink datatypes -- bulky data takes longer to process.  Example:  a 4-byte `INT` `DayOfMonth` could be a 1-byte `TINYINT UNSIGNED`.

You are moving a `TIMESTAMP` into a `DATETIME`.  This may or may not work as you expect.

`INT UNSIGNED` is OK for IPv4, but you can't fit IPv6 in it.

`COUNT(*)` probably does not need a 4-byte `INT`; see the smaller variants.

Use `UNSIGNED` where appropriate.

A mac-address takes 19 bytes the way you have it; it could easily be converted to/from a 6-byte `BINARY(6)`.  See `REPLACE()`, `UNHEX()`, `HEX()`, etc.

What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  It could be about 100G for the big RAM you have.

Do the time ranges overlap?  If not, take advantage of that.  Also, don't include unnecessary columns in the `PRIMARY KEY`, such as `EndTime`.

Have the `GROUP BY` columns in the same order as the `PRIMARY KEY` of knn_data; this will avoid a lot of block splits during the `INSERT`.

The big problem is that there is no useful index in `calibration_data`, so the `JOIN` has to do a full table scan again and again!  An extimated 2K scans of 3M rows!  Let me focus on that problem...

There is no good way to do `WHERE x BETWEEN start AND end` because MySQL does not know whether the datetime ranges overlap.  There is no real cure for that in this context, so let me approach it differently...

Are start and end 'regular'?  Like every hour?  Of so, we can do some sort of computation *instead* of the `BETWEEN`.  Let me know if this is the case; I will continue my thoughts.

Comment: Hi Rick! In this shape it is a one time thing, but it had a huge impact in learning about performance until now! So your answer is very useful for future improvements!! I will test your recommended improvements later with the smaller types!

- The inclusion of between is known!

- Our innodb_buffer is at 104 GB

- The timeranges are not regular, they differ in 4-18 minutes

So thanks for the input! Best Felix

Comment: I'm glad you see this as a learning experience.  104G -- good; perhaps all the data remained cached; so it was >24h of one CPU core.  (Sorry, no parallelism available.)  Irregular time ranges -- I could devise a complex scheme, but don't want to (my brain would hurt).

Comment: (I'd be happy to accept the "accepted solution" from the other answer.)

Comment: To be honest, the other answer was not as detailed as yours, which brought me a lot of insights. But the improvement to split the ` on between X and Y ` into `LEFT join calibration_data m
          ON m.visit >= cal.BeginTime 
 WHERE m.visit <= cal.EndTime` brought the asked impact on execution time by decreasing the filtered value from 100 to 11. But i rated your anser up ;)

Comment: This is exactly the point of my answer. Yes it will scan for more rows than a BETWEEN, but it will scan their index only instead of doing a full table scan. And I have been downvoted. Wonderfull SO rage.

Comment: @Felix - At this point, it would be helpful for Felix to do some benchmarks of the competing techniques.

Comment: The benchmark is done. The on where solution was finished after 3h.... So I would say unexpected behaviour for me as well because i thought the between solution would be better but the runtime defined a clear winner

Comment: When benchmarking, be sure to have the cache (buffer_pool) in a consistent state -- Such as restarting mysqld before each run.